# Empty page on sql - php querying

Tags: php, html, sql, querying

I'm making a website where people can see their personal stats. I'm doing this by retrieving SQL data with a php system. Here are my 2 files :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Search</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="query" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the file that is loaded when a user clicks on search :

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Medionakoya0102") or die("Error 
connecting to database: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("isolate") or die(mysql_error());
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Search results</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <?php
$query = $_GET['query']; 
$min_length = 3;
if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 

    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Player
        WHERE (`name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`uuid` LIKE '%".$query."%')") 
 or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){

            echo "<p><h3>".$results['join_date']."</h3>".$results['gems']." 
</p>";
        }

    }
    else{
        echo "No results";
    }

}
else{
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Now the problem is, the index loads, but when I click on search, sometimes the page is just blank, or it gives me an error : HTTP ERROR 500

Hope someone can help

Comment: This is likely due to your use of the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: So use something like mysqli_connect ? I already tried that, but didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

A 500 HTTP error is a response from the webserver, so your form is submitting correctly but there is most likely an error from PHP.  Check your web server logs for an error message correlating to the form submissions.  If you're not sure what the error is telling you please edit your question to include the error and I'm sure we can get it solved.

Also, some information about your environment would be useful: which webserver are you using, what's your PHP version, etc.

Comment: It says that there is an error at line 2, that's the connect form.

Comment: Tried with the mysqli thing that Alex showed, but didn't help either

Comment: @TristanVermeesch the next step is to figure out that error. Can you post that line from your log?